# How are <$> and <*> pronounced?

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

I am learning Haskell. One of the exercises I was asked to do was to compute all sums of a power set of a set of integers, e.g.:

```
allSums [1, 2, 5] -- should be [8,3,6,1,7,2,5,0]
```

I came up with this after reading about applicatives and functors, to which lists belong. It worked.

```
allSums :: [Int] -> [Int]
allSums [] = [0]
allSums (x:xs) =
  if x == 0 
  then allSums xs
  else (+) <$> [x, 0] <*> allSums xs
```

I was shook. It looks so terse, but it appears correct.

I do not know whom to talk to. My friends and parents think I am crazy.
How do you pronounce `<$>` and `<*>`? How do you even describe to people  what they do?

Comment: Another approach you could try would be `allSums = map sum . filterM (const [False, True])`. It doesn't have quite the same semantics, because you do some weird special-casing of zero. To be truly faithful, you need `allSums = map sum . filterM (const [False, True]) . filter (/= 0)`.

Comment: I voted to reopen because this asks for the _meaning_ of it, despite the "pronunciation" wording.

Comment: Yeah, I almost closed as a duplicate of the same question but I don't think this is really primarily about pronunciation.

Comment: Want to really blow your mind? This can also be written as `allSums = map sum . traverse (\x -> nub [x,0])`. Besides being even more terse, it works for non-list containers.

Comment: are you sure you commented under the answer you intended to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When reading these to myself, I do not pronounce them; they are just a visual glyph in my mind. If I must speak them aloud, I would say "eff-map" for `<$>` (possibly "eff-mapped onto" if there's some ambiguity) and "app" for `<*>` (possibly "applied to" if there's ambiguity), which come from the pre-`Applicative` names `fmap` and `ap`.

Also, I hate saying `fmap` out loud. For this reason and others, I would likely mentally transform this to

```
pure (+) <*> [x,0] <*> allSums xs
```

before I said it so that I only need to pronounce `pure` and `(<*>)`. As an aside, I actually find it a little bit surprising that this style is not more common; especially when spreading applicative arguments across multiple lines, this is more uniform, as

```
pure f
    <*> a
    <*> b
    <*> c
```

doesn't need to treat the `a` line specially.

Comment: i like this because it answers my original question, which not simply how to pronounce `<$>` and `<*>`, but why.

Comment: OMG I JUST DISCOVERED THAT LIFTA2 CAN BE USED IN CONJUNCTION WITH DATA CONSTRUCTORS.  okay I mean, I should've expected that that would work, but still, what a delight.

Answer (score 4):

You pronounce this combination pattern of `<$>` and `<*>` as ***`liftA2`***:

```
liftA2 :: Applicative f 
       => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
```

So then in your case `f ~ []`, `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, and

```
liftA2 :: Num a 
       => (a->a->a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
--        (+)  ...

(+) <$> [x,0] <*> allSums xs
=
[(x +), (0 +)] <*> allSums xs
=
liftA2 (+)  [x,0]  (allSums xs)
=
[x + r | x <- [x,0], r <- allSums xs]
```

and what they "do" in the case of lists is to form the Cartesian product-like combinations of the constituents and apply the function to each of the combinations.

In your case of summing the elements, using `0` for an element is like skipping over it completely. Thus indeed implementing the sums of the power set of numbers:

```
allSums [x1, x2, ..., xn]
=
[x1 + r | x1 <- [x1,0], r <- allSums [x2, ..., xn]]
=
[x1 + r | x1 <- [x1,0], r <- [x2 + r | x2 <- [x2,0], r <- allSums [x3, ..., xn]]]
=
[x1 + x2 + r | x1 <- [x1,0], x2 <- [x2,0], r <- allSums [x3, ..., xn]]
=
...
=
[x1 + x2 + ... + xn + r | x1 <- [x1,0], x2 <- [x2,0], ..., xn <- [xn,0], r <- [0]]
=
[x1 + x2 + ... + xn | x1 <- [x1,0], x2 <- [x2,0], ..., xn <- [xn,0]]
```

As to the pronunciation, I read `(+) <$> [x, 0] <*> allSums xs` as "plus *over* `x`-and-0 *over* all sums of `x`es".

As Daniel Wagner comments under the question, `[x, 0]` could be tweaked into `[x | x /= 0] ++ [0]`, for efficiency.